# porting-desktop-apps-to-net-core worked before

Tags: c#

I've been using this tutorial many times before and had never a issue. Since I updated my visual studio i get this.

[image: error example]

I get the follow error after following this tutorial: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/porting-desktop-apps-to-net-core/

I'm using the Guna.dll for my text and buttons.

Can anyone help me, give me more information about the problem/error?

```
        System.TypeInitializationException
      HResult=0x80131534
      Message=The type initializer for 'A.c5596ad7eebefb7cfe22f22c88ed940ca' threw an exception.
      Source=Guna.UI
      StackTrace:
       at A.c5596ad7eebefb7cfe22f22c88ed940ca.c28713f1a30f3f2105e30cc9d10f7ef4a()
       at Guna.UI.WinForms.GunaLabel..ctor()
       at Nettoya.FormHome.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\b\Desktop\Nettoya\Nettoya\Form1.Designer.cs:line 37
       at Nettoya.FormHome..ctor() in C:\Users\b\Desktop\Nettoya\Nettoya\Form1.cs:line 49
       at Nettoya.Program.Main() in C:\Users\b\Desktop\Nettoya\Nettoya\Program.cs:line 18
    
    Inner Exception 1:
    TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

[image: error example]

Comment: When was the last time code worked?  Did you make any changes since last time it worked?  If you updated from core 2.0/2.1 see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0  You may also have issue with TLS 1.2.  TLS 1.0/1.1 was obsoleted and stopped working on most servers in June.  You have to make sure you have the latest API/dlls to work with TLS 1.2.

Comment: [That class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.network?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't exist on .NET Core, so makes sense that it cannot be found

Comment: @jdweng The last time was in February this year. I changed back to net472 change a spelling mistake and added a small icon and now this error is what i get.

Comment: I would manually try a browser and enter same URL you are using in your code.  A browser will give a better error message to help determine root cause of issue.

Comment: Due to the brutal removal of certain types from .NET Core 3.x (compared to .NET Framework), reusing a .NET Framework based assembly in your .NET Core apps is highly risky. I maintained DockPanel Suite and another library, so I believe it is a rather common issue. You have to ask the vendor for a .NET Core specific build, and that's the only way to resolve such issues.